# How to define a list of Object as attribute in Model?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My data structure would be something like this.

```
{
product: {
    brand: "",
    category: "",
    rows: [
        {model: "", price: 123},
        {model: "", price: 345}
    ]
}
}




App.ListTransform = DS.Transform.extend({
    deserialize: function(serialized) {
        return serialized;
    },
    serialize: function(deserialized) {
        return deserialized;
    }
});
```

I want to know what's the difference between `Transform list` and `hasMany and belongs to` definition.

Comment: Transform list being the thing you made up?

Comment: @kingpin2k yes, I use `rows: DS.attr('list')` to define my model, I don't know if it is right

Answer (score 0):

Ember strongly supports the concept of a long living web page (SPA).  That being said client side you might view the same record multiple times.  Ember Data has a store where it keeps track of records (by their primary key, generally id).

#### General Example of the benefit of Ember Data

1. Request `product` with id `1`
2. The store will make a call to your server, wait for response... then build up the record and have it available.
3. Later, Request `product` with id 1
4. The store immediately returns the already fetched record giving your user an excellent user experience.

#### Why this is important

Let's take your `rows` above and assume they really are different products.  Once you add them to your cart you really want to keep track of `model v2, id 987`.  You then want to keep track of this, not just some string attached in json.

Comment: I have knew that answer. If I define through `hasMany and belongTo`, the childObject must have `id`, that's not I want. That turn it into a relation database based input.

Comment: I'm sorry, what's your question then?